# c# ASP.NET Membership issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

```
        NumberUsersOnlineLabel.Text = Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline().ToString();
        PasswordMinLengthLabel.Text = Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength.ToString();
        PasswordMinNoAlphaNumericLabel.Text Membership.MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters.ToString();
        TotalNumberofUsersLabel.Text = Membership.GetAllUsers().Count.ToString();

  MembersList.Text = Membership.GetAllUsers().ToString();
```

I would like the MemberList list box to display all user names in my membership db. but I can't seem to get it working correctly

Comment: What kind of control is MembersList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Membership.GetAllUsers()` returns a collection of users. If you call `.ToString()` on that collection you will not automatically get all user names. Instead you will get the name of the collection class itself (`MembershipUserCollection`).

Instead you want to display for each user the user's name for example. For this you need to use data binding to bind the collection of users to the list control. You can specify what property of each member to display in the control by setting the [`DataTextField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield.aspx) property (I chose "UserName", but you can chose any of the [MembershipUser properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser_properties.aspx)).

```
MembersList.DataTextField = "UserName";
MembersList.DataSource = Membership.GetAllUsers();
MembersList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the collection returned by `GetAllUsers()` and concatenate the usernames into a `StringBuilder`.